# Black-box secret sharing schemes

Tags: secret-sharing, threshold-cryptography

Do black box secret sharing schemes *[DF90, DF94]* have any advantages over the better-known secret sharing schemes like Shamir’s *[Sham79]*?

[DF90]: **Threshold cryptosystems**, by Desmedt, Yvo and Frankel, Yair, *in CRYPTO' 89*, 1990

[DF94]: **Homomorphic Zero-Knowledge Threshold Schemes over any Finite Abelian Group**, by Desmedt, Yvo G. and Frankel, Yair, *in SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics*, 1994, [[URL]](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895480192224713)

[Sham79]: **How to Share a Secret**, by Shamir, Adi, *in Commun. ACM*, 1979, [[URL]](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/359168.359176)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do!

To quote [CF02], *"A black-box secret sharing scheme for the threshold access structure $T_{t,n}$ is one which works over [secrets from] any ﬁnite Abelian group $G$*.

In contrast, Shamir secret sharing works only over secrets from a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

[CF02]: **Optimal Black-Box Secret Sharing over Arbitrary Abelian Groups**, by Ronald Cramer and Serge Fehr, *in Cryptology ePrint Archive, Paper 2002/036*, 2002, [[URL]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/036)

Comment: You should use $F_q$ for the finite field, since a ring $Z_q$ is not a field unless $q$ is prime. Furthermore, since the "secrets" are encodings of some real world information, it would be great if you could elaborate if there are any *other* advantages to black box secret sharing--there may well be.

Comment: Fixed, thank you! Will have to think a bit about other advantages.

Comment: Shamir secret sharing can also work over more general rings, even non-commutative ones https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1025.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [DF94], a way of sharing trapdoor functions is exploited. See [SDFY94].

[SDFY94]:  **How to share a function securely**, by Alfredo De Santis, Yvo Desmedt, Yair Frankel, and Moti Yung, in Proceedings of the twenty-sixth annual ACM symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC '94).  https://doi.org/10.1145/195058.195405